# Should I use dataset or datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I need to fetch one whole column from Table1 in the DB, should I fetch it using datatable or dataset? I can do both ways. I mean ok I should use Datatable. Why is that? What would happen if I use Dataset?

**ok that's what I wanted to know. So there's memory issue. Now I am confused. I mean whatever I use be it Datatable or Dataset, both will be fetching only ONE column frommy table in DB. How is Dateset's gonna use more memory then?**

Comment: There are other options beside DataTable & DataSet.  What are you planning on doing with the data?

Comment: data table should be good, Dataset is used why you have multiple results and relations.

Comment: If you only need **one** table, then there's absolutely no point or benefit in having a `DataSet`. Use a `DataTable` - or better yet: use an ORM to grab **objects** from your database - not rows and columns!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a DataTable.

A DataSet is an in-memory database while DataTable is an in-memory table.

DataSets are more complicated and heavier-weight; they can contain multiple DataTables and relations between DataTables.

Answer (score 2):

you can better use `DataTable`(uses less memory).

or you can try with user created `value objects` or [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your edited question, there's more overhead to a dataset. DataTables are better for what you need. If you're doing a lot of data fetching, though, it's easier (and way more maintainable!) to use an ORM of sorts.